# Adding a new row to a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame with both values and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex `DataFrame`:

```
                 predicted_y actual_y predicted_full actual_full
subj_id org_clip                                                
123     3                  2        5      [1, 2, 3]   [4, 5, 6]
```

That I wish to add a new row to:

```
                 predicted_y actual_y predicted_full   actual_full
subj_id org_clip                                                  
123     3                  2        5      [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]
321     4                 20       50   [10, 20, 30]  [40, 50, 60]    # add this row
```

And the following code does it:

```
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y']] = [20, 50]
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_full', 'actual_full']] = [[10,20,30], [40,50,60]]
```

**But** when trying to add a new row *in a single line*, I'm getting an error:

```
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y', 'predicted_full', 'actual_full']] = [20, 50, [10,20,30], [40,50,60]]

>>> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

### Notes:

I believe it has something (possibly syntactic) to do with me trying to add a row that contains both values and lists. All other attempts had raised the same error; see the following examples:

```
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y', ['predicted_full', 'actual_full']]] = [20, 50, [10,20,30], [40,50,60]]
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y', ['predicted_full'], ['actual_full']]] = [20, 50, [10,20,30], [40,50,60]]
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y', [['predicted_full'], ['actual_full']]]] = [20, 50, [10,20,30], [40,50,60]]
df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y', 'predicted_full', 'actual_full']] = [20, 50, np.array([10,20,30]), np.array([40,50,60])]
```

The code to construct the initial `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], labels=[[], []], names=['subj_id', 'org_clip']),
                  columns=['predicted_y', 'actual_y', 'predicted_full', 'actual_full'])
df.loc[('123', 3),['predicted_y', 'actual_y']] = [2, 5]
df.loc[('123', 3),['predicted_full', 'actual_full']] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make at least one of the sublists an array of dtype `object`:

```
In [27]: df.loc[('321', 4),['predicted_y', 'actual_y', 'predicted_full', 'actual_full']] =  (
           [20, 50, np.array((10, 20, 30), dtype='O'), [40, 50, 60]])

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
                 predicted_y actual_y predicted_full   actual_full
subj_id org_clip                                                  
123     3                  2        5      [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]
321     4                 20       50   [10, 20, 30]  [40, 50, 60]
```

---

Notice that the error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

occurs on this line:

```
--> 643         arr_value = np.array(value)
```

and can be reproduced like this

```
In [12]: np.array([20, 50, [10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f6122275ab9f> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([20, 50, [10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But if one of the sublists is an array of dtype object, then the result is an array of dtype object:

```
In [16]: np.array((20, 50, np.array((10, 20, 30), dtype='O'), (40, 50, 60)))
Out[16]: array([20, 50, array([10, 20, 30], dtype=object), (40, 50, 60)], dtype=object)
```

Thus the ValueError can be avoided.

Answer (score 8):

You can let `pd.Series` handle the `dtypes`

```
row_to_append = pd.Series([20, 50, [10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])
cols = ['predicted_y', 'actual_y', 'predicted_full', 'actual_full']
df.loc[(321, 4), cols] = row_to_append.values

df
```

[image]